# Adobe Flash AS2 to AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2

I made a AS2 file in Flash (it's a NavBar) and I'm trying to convert it to AS3. What changes will I have to make to these scripts to convert to AS3? (there are 3 layers of script):

**Layer 1:**

```
stop();

home.onRelease = function()
{
getURL("http://www.google.ca", _parent);        
}

maps.onRelease = function()
{
getURL("http://www.google.ca", _parent);    
}

forum.onRelease = function()
{
getURL("http://www.google.ca", _parent);
}

help.onRollOver = function()
{
gotoAndStop(2);     
}

more.onRollOver = function()
{
gotoAndStop(3);     
}
```

**Layer 2:**

```
stop();

faq.onRelease = function()
{
getURL("http://www.google.ca", _parent);        
}

howtos.onRelease = function()
{
getURL("http://www.google.ca", _parent);
}

edge.onRollOver = function()
{
gotoAndStop(1);     
}

background_1.onRollOver = function()
{
gotoAndStop(1);     
}

forum.onRollOver = function()
{
gotoAndStop(1);     
}

more.onRollOver = function()
{
gotoAndStop(3);     
}
```

**Layer 3:**

```
stop();

submit.onRelease = function()
{
getURL("http://www.google.ca", _parent);        
}

uwdclan.onRelease = function()
{
getURL("http://www.google.ca", _parent);        
}

edge_2.onRollOver = function()
{
gotoAndStop(1);     
}

background_2.onRollOver = function()
{
gotoAndStop(1);     
}

help.onRollOver = function()
{
gotoAndStop(2);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to use use an event listener, (and depending on what happens, removing event listeners might be a good idea too)

you can google for as3 even listeners, but here's the link to the first page to save you some time http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3events/

as far as converting your code for you goes, someone else might be interested in that :)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty minimal amount of work:

```
home.onRelease = function()
{
getURL("http://www.google.ca", _parent);        
}
```

becomes:

```
home.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function(e:MouseEvent){
    flash.net.navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.google.ca"), "_parent"); 
},false,0,true);
```

For rollOver, just replace `MouseEvent.CLICK` with `MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER` .  the gotoAndStop commands can stay the same